# Why does Bazel rebuild after a reboot or changing wireless networks?

Tags: c++, build, bazel

Why does [Google's Bazel](http://bazel.build) force rebuild C++ for reasons unrelated to code, such as rebooting the system or changing wireless networks? Even though code does not change, the code is rebuilt. In some other (inferior?) build systems the wireless network does not affect the dependency graph.

Asked another way: should all build systems, such as Microsoft Visual Studio also check the wireless network and the uptime of the machine before building code?

Asked a third way: what other environmental factors should be taken into account in the dependency graph? Antivirus signatures? Version of Google Chrome? The last time you received a Facebook Message?

Comment: Do you have a link to a github issue that talks about this? Also, changing networks can affect the build if, for example, your build uses remote artifacts. (I'm not sure if Bazel makes the assumption that all resolutions to a remote resources are the same, though - I would expect so.)

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of things that can cause Bazel to conservatively rebuild software, if it can't prove that reusing previous results is safe.

Primarily, these are 1) the files that are declared as inputs to an action (this can include tools such as compilers), 2) the command-line used, and 3) the environment variables that are passed to the action.

Bazel currently forwards a few environment variables from your local machine to all actions by default, including PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and TMPDIR - this is a bug (see https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2574).

Furthermore, Bazel supports 'stamping', which embeds information such as the username, hostname, and the current time into binaries. By default, stamping is disabled for binaries that are used during the build - these are built for what we call the 'host configuration'.

Possible things that could be going wrong:

1. It seems unlikely that PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or TMPDIR change if you change wireless networks, but you might want to check if that is the case.
2. Your Bazel builds might be configured to take some environment variable from the local machine and forward it to actions. Any time that env variable changes, Bazel will rebuild every action that depends on it. This can happen if --action_env=VARIABLE is passed to Bazel.
3. On Mac machines, the hostname can change depending on the network connection. What could happen here is that you are using a tool during the build and it's accidentally build with stamping enabled, and your hostname changes, so Bazel rebuilds the tool, and this poisons a large number of downstream actions because the tool is different (even if it's just a few bytes).
4. What could also happen is that Bazel's UI is confusing. If you restart the machine (or shutdown the Bazel daemon), then Bazel goes through all actions to check if they're cache hits, but may not say so correctly. You can rule this out by checking how long Bazel takes - if it's only a few seconds, then it's unlikely that it's actually executing anything. If this is the case here, then we'd like to know that so we can prioritize improvements in this area.

Edit: There's also the possibility that you found an actual bug in Bazel, for example that Bazel is non-deterministic in some way and gets a cache miss due to the current key not exactly matching the previous entry.

Answer (score 0):

It's just being paranoid.  Rebooting or changing wireless networks can result in the system time being updated to an earlier time than the last build.  This can result in things not being rebuilt that should be, so it is taking the safer (of longer) route of rebuilding everything.

Comment: Bazel doesn't use system time to determine incremental changes. Your example could happen anyway, just by someone changing the time on an otherwise-unchanged machine.

Comment: @GManNickG System time changes effect file times when the file is changed.  Does it track the file time, or does it look for OS notifications that files have been changed?