# Bazel recompiles everything every time I restart my machine

Tags: c++, bazel, mediapipe

I have started creating a program with the Mediapipe library in C++ on Windows and build all my source code and their source code using Bazel. As I couldn't get anything else to work, I have put my own source code inside the Mediapipe source tree and use their WORKSPACE file in addition to custom BUILD files written by me.

My main problem at the moment is that Bazel rebuilds all the mediapipe source code every time my machine is restarted, which takes around 30 minutes. This is rather annoying. When the initial build has completed however, it only recompiles source files which have changed which takes usually takes less than 30 seconds. The command I use to build is `bazel build --compilation_mode=dbg --define MEDIAPIPE_DISABLE_GPU=1 //mediapipe/mydirectory:myprogram`. If I execute `bazel shutdown` and then rebuild it is still fast. The problem seems to occur in both cmder and powershell (haven't tried cmd.exe).

Comment: *"As I couldn't get anything else to work, I have put my own source code inside the Mediapipe source tree"* - Then you should probably ask how to avoid this.

Comment: I essentially asked that in my previous question. Nobody responded.

Comment: https://www.tweag.io/blog/2022-09-15-hermetic-bazel/ -> DETECTING HERMETICITY ISSUES

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46674110/why-does-bazel-rebuild-after-a-reboot-or-changing-wireless-networks